# MySQL queries, max & current rank for players

Tags: mysql

In the lists of players I need to find find the maximum rating and current rating

```
Petr | 1 | 2016-12-01 00:00:00 
Petr | 2 | 2016-12-02 00:00:00 
Petr | 3 | 2016-12-03 00:00:00 
Oleg | 3 | 2016-12-01 00:00:00 
Oleg | 2 | 2016-12-02 00:00:00 
Oleg | 1 | 2016-12-03 00:00:00
```

I want to get a Output:

```
 name | min | current  
 Petr |  1  | 3 
 Oleg |  1  | 1
```

For to find the maximum, I try

```
SELECT t1.rank as min
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2
ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.rank > t2.rank
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
```

And other solve, for find the current

```
SELECT t1.rank as current
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.dt=(SELECT MAX(dt) FROM table t2 WHERE t1.name = t2.name)
```

Comment: Just wanted to point out that you ask for maximum rating, yet your output showcases a 'min' column. Which one do you mean?

Comment: The point of SO is to **help** you to find a solution to a question, not to do the entire work from scratch instead of you. Pls share what you have tried so far (include your code) to solve your question and what went wrong with it. Also, SO being a Q/A site, you must ask a question in your post. Otherwise there is nothing for us to answer.

Comment: Fernando, Maximum it is min() =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the minimum rating not maximum.

To get `current`, the rating with max date, use `GROUP BY` and then join the original table again, to get the rating value for this max date:

```
SELECT
  t1.Name,
   MAX(t2.MinRating) AS MinRating,
  MAX(t1.Rating) AS Current
FROM yourTable AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT Name, MIN(rating) AS MinRating, MAX(rateDate) AS MaxRateDate
  FROM yourTable
  GROUP BY Name
) AS t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name AND t1.rateDate = t2.MaxRateDate
GROUP BY t1.Name;
```

[fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a22a95/3)

```
| Name | MinRating | Current |
|------|-----------|---------|
| Oleg |         1 |       1 |
| Petr |         1 |       3 |
```

Comment: I upvoted so you won't get so frustrated :) But I believe that the reason might be because the OP didn't show any efforts on their behalf (as expected from anyone who ask a question on SO), so questions like this should be closed, until the OP show us what they tried before asking

Comment: Excuse me, I asked a question, but did not show the solutions that I tried.

Comment: @WinCC although I can sympathise with your frustration, you should really watch your communication! Outbursts like yours keep many people from commenting once they have downvoted a question. I saw the original post by the OP when you posted your answer. There was **no** question to be answered at that time, just a dump of unclear requirements. You chose to take a shot at it, sy chose to downvote you for doing so. I can understand the downvoters as well.

Comment: @WinCC, Understood, thanks again! Only not necessary MAX(). `SELECT t1.Name, t2.MinRating AS MinRating, t1.Rating AS Current`